# Connect Mac to an external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My system is OS X Yosemite. When I connect MBP to a monitor, the monitor shows no signal error and the MacBook screen also becomes black. Disconnecting will not make the MacBook screen normal again. I have to force it to shut down and restart. 
I also don't have the "detect display" option in system preference -> display. Does anyone have the same problem?

=======

MacBook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2012. Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5. Memory 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3. Graphics Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB. The cable is VGA-mini displayport (not Apple brand, but worked fine with projectors before). The monitor is AOC E2752VH (model #: 270LM00004)

Comment: We'll ned a little more info. Start with the exact make/model of Macbook, what connector & cable you are using (on both ends {EG Lightning to HDMI}) and what make and model of monitor you are connecting to.

Comment: Macbook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2012. Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5. Memory 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3. Graphics Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB. The cable is VGA-mini displayport (not Apple brand, but worked fine with projectors before). The monitor is AOC E2752VH (model #: 270LM00004). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Those specifications and those of the cable and monitor indicate that it *should* work.

You could try resetting the SMC on that Mac by shutting down the Mac holding down the Shift+Control+Option keys and the Power button at the same time. Wait 15 sec and then turn it back on.

Failing that you could start in Safe Mode by holding the shift key while booting (booting will take a lot longer) and try plugging in the monitor then.

Failing those I would try another adapter, preferably one with an all digital signal path like a Mini Displayport to HDMI or DVI-D

Comment: Thanks! The first 2 options did not work. I guess I will have to try a new adaptor.

Comment: Since your monitor is display port, you should get a mini-display port  to display port cable, and connect it via the Thunderbolt port on the Mac, since it is a display port port anyway. skip VGA.  https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Mini-DisplayPort-Cable-Feet/dp/B013PWQPFS/ref=sr_1_3_acs_sk_pb_1_sl_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1547139277&sr=1-3-acs&keywords=mini+displayport+to+displayport+cable

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "zapping the PRAM" can fix issues like this. To reset the PRAM, restart your computer and at the chime (on pre-2016 models), press and hold down Command+Option+P+R. After a short pause, the computer will restart. Continue to hold all the keys down until the 3rd chime then release to let the computer start up normally. 
This has resolved display problems for me and a number of my clients. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks! But this does not work for me. T_T